# how to performance tune jbpm meta repository

Tags: postgresql, performance, jbpm

I'm using Postgres as a meta-repository for JBPM to store workflow state. We  pretty much optimized the configuration for the database.

Yet I see some slowness in the database. Talking with dba he suggested to partition the tables preferably  `processinstancelog`, `variableinstancelog`.

Has anyone successfully implemented database partitioning at the same time without compromising functionality of jbpm?

Other suggestion I had tried is cleanup rows for completed processes. While this does helps to a certain level I faced during the delete it locks the table causes performance issues hence that leads to bring down the db environment only for maintenance which I cannot afford right now.

Comment: I suggest you partition those tables, see if it causing any problems with "functionality of jbpm", if it does attempt to deal with them and come back to SO only if you are unsuccessful with that. Describe difficulty you are having and someone will more likely help.

Comment: I came across a feature in postgresql which helped me partition the tables based on the date range this has tremendously helped performance. [link](https://read.acloud.guru/how-to-partition-dynamically-in-postgresql-ce3acbaef66c) provided has sample code on how to accomplish dynamic partition in postresql.